# Teams Permissions for Reading and Writing Chat Messages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am building a workflow that posts a message to a specific person in teams for review and approval. I believe I have the API call correct, but I keep getting this.

"code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
"message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",

What permissions or privileges do I need to interact with the API? Does the Application/User have to be an administrator?

Comment: Which api are you calling? What permissions did you grant?

Comment: Hi @koehler, Could You please let us know which API you are using and permissions enabled?
Please have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) API Document.

Comment: Microsoft Graph Rest API v1

Comment: @Koehler, To enable API permissions user has to be an admin and Could you please try the same in Graph Explorer and share screenshots.

Comment: @Koehler, Is the issue resolved? If not, could you please share us more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can send simple messages, messages with @mentions and cards to chat of a user or in a channel using a graph APIs:

- To send chat message in a channel, call
  POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/%7Bid%7D/channels/%7Bid%7D/messages)
- To send message to chat, call
  POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/{id}/messages](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/%7Bid%7D/messages)

For more information related to permissions and request details refer [API document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

Administrator have to enable delegated Graph API permissions as listed in document, by registering an app in Azure to avail these APIs in Source code.